# Don't caching images in Blogger

Tags: javascript, image, caching, blogger, blogspot

I need to disable cache for images in my blog (blogspot)

```
<img src="/http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
```

When i refresh my browser  images in my blog are not updated.
Only if i delete browser history i get updated image.
Because images coming from remote hosts (webcam sources)
and they are often updated i need to  display last saved image in browser so i don't want images cached from blogger
I'm open to javascript or any other solution

Thanks

Ps i resolved with javascript trick adding dummy timestamp to img tag

Answer (score 1):

you cannot achieve this through javascript, the remote host that is serving the image can set the cache headers so browsers do not cache image.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

also it would be good practice to change the image name, every time you change the image so you wont have to worry about caching.

Comment: ok.. but i can't modify  remote hosts  however thanks for answer